# Three 4k monitor setup not working properly

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon

I am a noob in Linux systems although I have been using Linux for a few years.

I have a 3 4k@60 monitor setup that I was running without any issues in my Mint 21.1. One monitor was horizontally placed and the other 2 were vertically placed on each side the horizontal one. I have 3080 ti GPU and 2 monitors are connected with HDMI and the other one is connected with DisplayPort.

After I moved house, I saw that the middle monitor's display was split and the right side of the display is showing part of the screen of the right monitor. The left side of the display shows the middle monitor's screen.

I tried solving it in the display settings. Tried disabling monitors and enabling back in but no luck. So I installed the new Mint 21.2 and still seeing this issue. (I have a dual boot setup with Windows and Linux).

I saw that others pasted the output of inxi -Fxxxrz and xrander so I am also pasting the outputs of my system here.

inxi -Fxxxrz output:

```
  Kernel: 5.15.0-76-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 11.3.0
    Desktop: Cinnamon 5.8.4 tk: GTK 3.24.33 wm: muffin vt: 7 dm: LightDM 1.30.0
    Distro: Linux Mint 21.2 Victoria base: Ubuntu 22.04 jammy
Machine:
  Type: Desktop System: ASUS product: N/A v: N/A serial: <superuser required>
  Mobo: ASUSTeK model: TUF GAMING B660-PLUS WIFI D4 v: Rev 1.xx
    serial: <superuser required> UEFI: American Megatrends v: 2212
    date: 12/13/2022
CPU:
  Info: 16-core (8-mt/8-st) model: 12th Gen Intel Core i9-12900 bits: 64
    type: MST AMCP smt: enabled arch: Alder Lake rev: 2 cache: L1: 1.4 MiB
    L2: 14 MiB L3: 30 MiB
  Speed (MHz): avg: 1897 high: 4958 min/max: 800/5000:5100:3800 cores:
    1: 800 2: 1072 3: 3570 4: 800 5: 800 6: 800 7: 800 8: 787 9: 3350 10: 4875
    11: 4701 12: 4958 13: 3098 14: 1076 15: 855 16: 800 17: 996 18: 799
    19: 800 20: 801 21: 3599 22: 3791 23: 801 24: 800 bogomips: 116121
  Flags: avx avx2 ht lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx
Graphics:
  Device-1: NVIDIA GA102 [GeForce RTX 3080 Ti] vendor: Gigabyte
    driver: nouveau v: kernel pcie: speed: 16 GT/s lanes: 16 ports:
    active: DP-3,HDMI-A-1,HDMI-A-2 empty: DP-1,DP-2 bus-ID: 01:00.0
    chip-ID: 10de:2208 class-ID: 0300
  Device-2: AVerMedia Live Streamer CAM 313 type: USB
    driver: snd-usb-audio,uvcvideo bus-ID: 1-9.4:7 chip-ID: 07ca:313a
    class-ID: 0102 serial: <filter>
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.4 driver: X: loaded: modesetting
    unloaded: fbdev,vesa gpu: nouveau display-ID: :0 screens: 1
  Screen-1: 0 s-res: 8160x3840 s-dpi: 96 s-size: 2159x1016mm (85.0x40.0")
    s-diag: 2386mm (93.9")
  Monitor-1: DP-3 pos: primary,top-left model: Redmi 27 NU serial: <filter>
    res: 2160x3840 hz: 60 dpi: 164 size: 335x597mm (13.2x23.5")
    diag: 685mm (27") modes: max: 3840x2160 min: 720x400
  Monitor-2: HDMI-1 mapped: HDMI-A-1 pos: primary,top-right
    model: Redmi 27 NU serial: <filter> res: 2160x3840 dpi: 164
    size: 335x597mm (13.2x23.5") diag: 685mm (27") modes: max: 3840x2160
    min: 720x400
  Monitor-3: HDMI-2 mapped: HDMI-A-2 pos: bottom-c
    model: LG (GoldStar) HDR 4K serial: <filter> res: 3840x2160 hz: 60 dpi: 163
    size: 600x340mm (23.6x13.4") diag: 690mm (27.2") modes: max: 3840x2160
    min: 640x480
  OpenGL: renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 15.0.6 256 bits) v: 4.5 Mesa 22.2.5
    direct render: Yes
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel vendor: ASUSTeK driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel
    bus-ID: 00:1f.3 chip-ID: 8086:7ad0 class-ID: 0403
  Device-2: NVIDIA GA102 High Definition Audio vendor: Gigabyte
    driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel pcie: speed: 16 GT/s lanes: 16
    bus-ID: 01:00.1 chip-ID: 10de:1aef class-ID: 0403
  Device-3: Generalplus USB Audio Device type: USB
    driver: hid-generic,snd-usb-audio,usbhid bus-ID: 1-9.3:5 chip-ID: 1b3f:2008
    class-ID: 0300
  Device-4: AVerMedia Live Streamer CAM 313 type: USB
    driver: snd-usb-audio,uvcvideo bus-ID: 1-9.4:7 chip-ID: 07ca:313a
    class-ID: 0102 serial: <filter>
  Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k5.15.0-76-generic running: yes
  Sound Server-2: PulseAudio v: 15.99.1 running: yes
  Sound Server-3: PipeWire v: 0.3.48 running: yes
Network:
  Device-1: Intel driver: iwlwifi v: kernel port: N/A bus-ID: 00:14.3
    chip-ID: 8086:7af0 class-ID: 0280
  IF: wlo1 state: up mac: <filter>
  Device-2: Intel Ethernet I225-V vendor: ASUSTeK driver: igc v: kernel
    pcie: speed: 5 GT/s lanes: 1 port: N/A bus-ID: 05:00.0 chip-ID: 8086:15f3
    class-ID: 0200
  IF: enp5s0 state: down mac: <filter>
Bluetooth:
  Device-1: Intel AX201 Bluetooth type: USB driver: btusb v: 0.8
    bus-ID: 1-14:8 chip-ID: 8087:0026 class-ID: e001
  Report: hciconfig ID: hci0 rfk-id: 0 state: up address: <filter>
    bt-v: 3.0 lmp-v: 5.2 sub-v: 356b hci-v: 5.2 rev: 356b
RAID:
  Hardware-1: Intel Volume Management Device NVMe RAID Controller driver: vmd
    v: 0.6 port: N/A bus-ID: 00:0e.0 chip-ID: 8086:467f rev: class-ID: 0104
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 2.73 TiB used: 11.19 GiB (0.4%)
  ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: Samsung model: SSD 970 EVO Plus 2TB
    size: 1.82 TiB speed: 31.6 Gb/s lanes: 4 type: SSD serial: <filter>
    rev: 4B2QEXM7 temp: 35.9 C scheme: GPT
  ID-2: /dev/sda vendor: Toshiba model: DT01ACA100 size: 931.51 GiB
    speed: 6.0 Gb/s type: HDD rpm: 7200 serial: <filter> rev: A750 scheme: MBR
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 186.68 GiB used: 11.16 GiB (6.0%) fs: ext4
    dev: /dev/nvme0n1p7
  ID-2: /boot/efi size: 96 MiB used: 31.1 MiB (32.3%) fs: vfat
    dev: /dev/nvme0n1p1
Swap:
  ID-1: swap-1 type: file size: 2 GiB used: 0 KiB (0.0%) priority: -2
    file: /swapfile
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 27.8 C mobo: N/A
  Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A
Repos:
  Packages: apt: 2156
  No active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list
    1: deb http://packages.linuxmint.com victoria main upstream import backport
    2: deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy main restricted universe multiverse
    3: deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates main restricted universe multiverse
    4: deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse
    5: deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-security main restricted universe multiverse
Info:
  Processes: 449 Uptime: 4m wakeups: 0 Memory: 62.54 GiB
  used: 3.39 GiB (5.4%) Init: systemd v: 249 runlevel: 5 Compilers:
  gcc: 11.3.0 alt: 11/12 Shell: Bash v: 5.1.16 running-in: gnome-terminal
  inxi: 3.3.13
```

xrander output:

````
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 connected primary 2160x3840+6000+0 right (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 597mm x 335mm
   3840x2160     60.00 +  60.00    50.00    59.94    60.00*   30.00    29.97  
   3200x1800     60.00  
   2880x1620     60.00  
   2560x1600     60.00  
   2560x1440     60.00    60.00  
   2048x1536     60.00  
   1920x1440     60.00  
   1856x1392     60.00  
   1792x1344     60.00  
   2048x1152     60.00  
   1920x1200     60.00  
   1920x1080     75.00    60.00    60.00    50.00    59.94    60.00  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     60.00    59.88  
   1400x1050     60.00  
   1600x900      60.00    60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02    60.00  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1400x900      60.00  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1440x810      60.00  
   1368x768      60.00  
   1280x800      60.00    59.91  
   1152x864      75.00    60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94    60.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.00  
   896x672       60.00  
   1024x576      60.00  
   960x600       60.00  
   832x624       60.00  
   960x540       60.00  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    60.00  
   840x525       60.00  
   864x486       60.00  
   720x576       50.00  
   700x525       60.00  
   800x450       60.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x512       60.00  
   700x450       60.00  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    60.00    59.94  
   720x405       60.00  
   720x400       70.08  
   684x384       60.00  
   576x432       60.00  
   640x360       60.00  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00  
   416x312       60.00  
   480x270       60.00  
   400x300       60.00  
   432x243       60.00  
   320x240       60.00  
   360x202       60.00  
   320x180       60.00  
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-2 connected 3840x2160+2160+365 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 600mm x 340mm
   3840x2160     60.00*+  50.00    59.94    60.00    30.00    30.00    25.00    24.00    29.97    23.98  
   3200x1800     60.00  
   2880x1620     60.00  
   2560x1600     60.00  
   2560x1440     60.00    59.95  
   2048x1536     60.00  
   1920x1440     60.00  
   1856x1392     60.00  
   1792x1344     60.00  
   2048x1152     60.00  
   1920x1200     60.00  
   1920x1080     60.00    50.00    59.94    60.00    30.00    24.00    29.97    23.98  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     60.00  
   1400x1050     60.00  
   1600x900      60.00    60.00  
   1280x1024     60.02    60.00  
   1400x900      60.00  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1440x810      60.00  
   1368x768      60.00  
   1280x800      60.00    59.91  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    60.00  
   1024x768      60.00    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.00  
   896x672       60.00  
   1024x576      60.00  
   960x600       60.00  
   960x540       60.00  
   800x600       60.32    60.00  
   840x525       60.00  
   864x486       60.00  
   720x576       50.00  
   700x525       60.00  
   800x450       60.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x512       60.00  
   700x450       60.00  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x405       60.00  
   684x384       60.00  
   640x360       60.00  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00  
   480x270       60.00  
   400x300       60.00  
   432x243       60.00  
   320x240       60.00  
   360x202       60.00  
   320x180       60.00  
DP-3 connected 2160x3840+0+0 left (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 597mm x 335mm
   3840x2160     60.00*+  29.56  
   3200x1800     60.00  
   2880x1620     60.00  
   2560x1600     74.97    59.99    60.00  
   2560x1440     60.00    60.00  
   2048x1536     60.00  
   1920x1440     75.00    60.00  
   1856x1392     75.00    60.00    60.00  
   1792x1344     75.00    60.00  
   2048x1152     60.00    60.00  
   1920x1200     74.93    59.88    60.00  
   1920x1080     75.00    60.00    60.00    50.00    59.94    60.00  
   1600x1200     75.00    70.00    65.00    60.00  
   1680x1050     74.89    59.95    60.00  
   1400x1050     74.87    60.00    59.98  
   1600x900      60.00    60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    71.96    60.02    60.00  
   1440x900      74.98    59.89  
   1400x900      60.00  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1440x810      60.00  
   1368x768      60.00  
   1280x800      74.93    59.81    60.00  
   1152x864      75.00    60.00  
   1280x768      74.89  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94    60.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.00  
   896x672       60.00  
   1024x576      60.00  
   960x600       60.00  
   832x624       60.00  
   960x540       60.00  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    60.00  
   840x525       60.00  
   864x486       60.00  
   720x576       50.00  
   700x525       60.00  
   800x450       60.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x512       60.00  
   700x450       60.00  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    60.00    59.94  
   720x405       60.00  
   720x400       70.08  
   684x384       60.00  
   576x432       60.00  
   640x360       60.00  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00  
   416x312       60.00  
   480x270       60.00  
   400x300       60.00  
   432x243       60.00  
   320x240       60.00  
   360x202       60.00  
   320x180       60.00  ```
````